# SoapUI load test terminates when limit is reached and then run again after which never stops

Tags: soapui, load-testing, terminate

I have a load test:
[image]

It was originally designed on version 5.0.1 of SoapUI (maybe 5.0.0) and later modified and currently used on 5.2.1.

When I run it from SOAP GUI it runs well and terminates in 30 seconds as is set in its limit.

But when I run it from Jenkins (shell script) or console it terminates in 30 seconds and then immediately re-runs. The second run is never got terminated Does anyone know how can I solve this issue? Maybe I do not understand some settings correctly?

Functional tests run without any issues.

Extract from the log which shows the moment when first run terminates and then test starts again:

```
[root@jenkins-cip cip-soapui-load-dev]# export SOAPUI_HOME=/opt/progs/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.2.1
[root@jenkins-cip cip-soapui-load-dev]# path=`pwd`
[root@jenkins-cip cip-soapui-load-dev]# $SOAPUI_HOME/bin/loadtestrunner.sh  -r -f/opt/progs/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.2.1/loadteststatistics -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false  -Gsoapui.properties=${path}/cip.dev.properties  CIP-smoke-test-load.xml
================================
=
= SOAPUI_HOME = /opt/progs/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.2.1
=
================================
12:28:26,753 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] Running LoadTest [LoginLoadTest]
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 1
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 2
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 3
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 4
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 5
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 6
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 7
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 8
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 9
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 10
Progress: 1 - Started thread 1
Progress: 1 - Started thread 2
Progress: 1 - Started thread 3
Progress: 1 - Started thread 4
Progress: 1 - Started thread 5
Progress: 1 - Started thread 6
Progress: 1 - Started thread 7
Progress: 1 - Started thread 8
Progress: 1 - Started thread 9
Progress: 1 - Started thread 10
12:28:26,802 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] LoadTest [LoginLoadTest] progress: 4.6666668E-4, 10
12:28:27,673 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:27,673 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:27,688 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:27,688 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:27,752 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:27,752 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:27,776 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:27,776 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:27,802 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] LoadTest [LoginLoadTest] progress: 0.0338, 10
12:28:27,830 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:27,830 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:27,882 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
12:28:27,882 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
12:28:27,901 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
12:28:27,901 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
12:28:27,908 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
12:28:27,908 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
12:28:27,923 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
12:28:27,924 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
12:28:27,972 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check
12:28:27,973 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:27,973 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:27,977 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
12:28:27,977 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
12:28:27,979 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check
12:28:27,981 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:27,981 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:27,992 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check
12:28:27,997 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
...
...
...
12:28:56,947 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
12:28:56,947 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
12:28:57,810 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] LoadTest [LoginLoadTest] finished with status FINISHED
12:28:57,810 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] Exporting log and statistics for LoadTest [LoginLoadTest]
12:28:57,813 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] Exported 2 log items to [/opt/progs/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.2.1/loadteststatistics/LoginLoadTest-log.txt]
12:28:57,813 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] Exported 0 error results
12:28:57,814 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] Exported 3 statistics to [/opt/progs/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.2.1/loadteststatistics/LoginLoadTest-statistics.txt]
12:28:57,814 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] Running LoadTest [LoadTest]
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 1
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 2
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 3
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 4
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 5
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 6
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 7
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 8
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 9
Progress: 1 - Creating Virtual User 10
Progress: 1 - Started thread 1
Progress: 1 - Started thread 2
Progress: 1 - Started thread 3
Progress: 1 - Started thread 4
Progress: 1 - Started thread 5
Progress: 1 - Started thread 6
Progress: 1 - Started thread 7
Progress: 1 - Started thread 8
Progress: 1 - Started thread 9
Progress: 1 - Started thread 10
12:28:57,841 INFO  [SoapUILoadTestRunner] LoadTest [LoadTest] progress: 2.5E-5, 10
12:28:58,613 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check
12:28:58,614 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:58,614 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:58,658 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check
12:28:58,659 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
12:28:58,659 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /cip/kn-BusinessPartner-V6 HTTP/1.1
12:28:58,699 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check
12:28:58,701 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
```

The same behaviour when run from a command line:

```
export SOAPUI_HOME=/opt/progs/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.2.1
path=`pwd`

$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/loadtestrunner.sh  -r -f/opt/progs/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.2.1/loadteststatistics -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false  -Gsoapui.properties=${path}/cip.dev.properties  CIP-smoke-test-load.xml
```

Comment: Do you observer the same behaviour when it is run from commandline? What is the command that is used in jenkins?

Comment: Yes, the same behaviour when run from command line (added to the post)

Comment: This is really strange.